# Component not instantiating when nested in Angular2

Tags: angularjs-directive, typescript, angular, nested

I have this component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'char-gen',
      template: '<div class="box" id="chargenApp">{{title}}</div>'
    })

    export class CharGenComponent {
      title = 'Character Creator';
    }
```

Which I'm calling from within this one:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<div class="box" id="appBox"><h1>{{title}}</h1><div class="divider"></div></div><div class="footer">{{copyright}}</div>'
    })

    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Order Of The Mouse: Phase 2 -- Operation Dovecot';
      copyright = 'Copyright © Sassafras Associated Ltd 2016'
    }
```

In this manner:

```
<my-app>Loading Order Of The Mouse
<char-gen>... [Character Generator Loading]</char-gen></my-app>
```

But the `<chargen>` component isn't appearing (the placeholder text in the directive does, but the actual component template doesn't instantiate). However, when I call `<char-gen>` without nesting it, like this:

```
 <my-app>Loading Order Of The Mouse</my-app>
 <char-gen>... [Character Generator Loading]</char-gen>
```

It shows up fine. What should I do to fix this problem? I wasn't even sure if I could do nesting this way, but supposedly it's possible so I'm wondering how to implement it so it works properly for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should first import the **chargen** component lets say in a file
>   chargen.ts(assume they are in the same directory with AppComponent)
>
> You should also put an element with the selector ***'char-gen'***
>
> in side the template of the **AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CharGenComponent } from '@chargen';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',    
    template: '<div class="box" id="appBox"><h1>{{title}}</h1><div class="divider"></div></div><div class="footer">{{copyright}}</div>
    <char-gen></char-gen>',
    directives: [CharGenComponent]
})

 export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Order Of The Mouse: Phase 2 -- Operation Dovecot';
      copyright = 'Copyright © Sassafras Associated Ltd 2016'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your `my-app` component about the existence of your other component like this:

```
import { CharGenComponent} from './char-gen.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ...,
  directives: [CharGenComponent]
})
```

You might have to modify the path to your `CharGenComponent` to reflect your file structure.

This [Angular 2 Tutorial chapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) has more information about making your components work together.